# Maven param that contains spaces in jenkins declarative pipeline

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, parameterization

Let's say that we have a jenkins pipeline that at some point we execute a maven parameterized build:

```
sh "mvn clean install -DparameterType=${parameter}"
```

What if the parameter's value contained spaces? Eg the value was "test param".

When running on IDE, this of course works:

```
mvn clean install -DparameterType="test param"
```

But if we do sth similar inside the pipeline, like

```
sh "mvn clean install -DparameterType=\"${parameter}\""
```

or

```
sh "mvn clean install -DparameterType=""${parameter}""
```

it doesn't and the param is passed like

```
-DparameterType=test param
```

which is not good for maven. Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you tried to use `'` single quotes instead... `"mvn clean install -DparameterType='${parameter}'"`

Comment: @khmarbaise yes of course. directly and by escaping the single quotes. Didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
 sh """
 mvn clean install -DparameterType=\"${parameter}\"
 """
```

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool : 3 as shown in the example

Comment: @gandalf_the_cool : can you just do an echo and test .``sh(script "echo \" ${PARAMETER}\"")``